# Create new Project in Angular-js

Tags: angularjs

I am new to `AngularJs`. I want to create a new project in angular-js . So , How can i create it using command prompt ?
I have tried `ng new myProject`. But it is giving some error like

```
ng new myProject
? Select project blueprint: (Use arrow keys)
> Default template
  Ui Router template
  Your own template from git
```

How can i create it ?

Comment: that's not an error - that's given you options to initialize

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://yeoman.io/ there are plenty of project template for angular.

You need node and npm for runn it

Answer (score 0):

This are just options to choose.
You can choose between the Default Project Setup, a Setup with ui-router configured or you can provide some own template from git.

I you are new to Anggular you may should try the Default Template. This will give you some impressions on best practices and how to structure you application